# Code to run Visual Basic Web App

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, azure

I'm sorry if this seems elementary, but I'm new to coding and need help understanding how to run a VB Web App.  I'm used to creating form applications in Windows and trigger my application with the loading of the form (or button click),

```
Private Sub Form_Load(sender As System.Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
```

How do I initiate my code in a web app in vb?

Comment: It's similar for Web Forms - each page has a `Page_Load` method.  But there are significant differences between Web Forms and WinForms applications.   Best to look at some ASP.NET tutorials and play around with it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check out some tutorials.

Comment: you check the asp.net  .

Comment: why is this tagged in azure?

Comment: I'm trying to host my app on azure... is there something I should consider going about this?